# Construct artificial slightly overlapping data for PCA plot

Tags: r, pca, dataset

I am trying to construct artificial data which show two distinct groups in a PCA plot. However, the two groups should still slightly overlap. The following approaches came the closest but I am still not happy with it. Even changing the parameters in `rnorm` and `runif` didn't work out. One group has always a much bigger spread than the other.

```
d1 <- {}
d2 <- {}
for(i in 1:20) {    
  d1 <- cbind(d1, rnorm(20, mean=100, sd=10))   
  d2 <- cbind(d2, rnorm(20, mean=110, sd=5))    
  # d1 <- rbind(d1, runif(100, 1,4))    
  # d2 <- rbind(d2, runif(100, 1,3))
}

d <- as.data.frame(rbind(d1,d2))
res <- prcomp(d, center = TRUE, scale = TRUE, na.action = na.omit)
d$group <- as.factor(c(rep("g1", 20), rep("g2", 20))) 
ggplot(d, aes(V1,V2)) +                 
  geom_point(aes(color = group), size=4)
```

Comment: I don't follow what you are trying to do here. You have 2 orthogonal vectors, not 2 groups represented on 2 different dimensions each; that's not a setup that's going to yield anything, although as I say, I don't grasp what you ultimately want to show.

Comment: well, two groups two vectors is pretty much the same. I think it is  pretty clear what I am trying to achieve. I want two data clouds that partially overlap in a PCA plot. However, the (magnitude of) spread of the two clouds should be similar. I thought of something like that here: http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-C1wH5zqefoo/T9-Yl45-bdI/AAAAAAAABFo/oLOknGxZuKw/s1600/color.png. Instead of having 3 groups I want just two like the one in green and blue they are also partially overlap.

Comment: Two groups-two vectors is not the same, which is why you're having difficulty. The picture helps. Lets say you get two groups that overlap somewhat on the 1st 2 principle components, what do you want to do with them? What is the point of this exercise?

Comment: Great we are talking about the same thing now :-) I want to use that plot to explain some biological circumstances.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To simulate a PCA, **start with the desired result and work backwards:** add some random error in the orthogonal directions and rotate that randomly.

The following example stipulates a two-dimensional result (*i.e.*, two principal components) with two "blobs"; it is readily extended to more blobs.  (More dimensions would take a bit more work in modifying `sigma` to accommodate higher-dimensional covariance matrices.)

Let's start with a **random rotation matrix**.

```
set.seed(17)
p <- 5     # dimensions
rot <- qr.Q(qr(matrix(rnorm(p^2), p)))
```

**We generate the blobs separately from different multivariate normal distributions**. The parameters (their means and covariance matrices) are buried in the `mvrnorm` arguments.  To make it easy and reliable to specify the shape of such a distribution, we create a small function `sigma` to convert the angle of the principal axis and the two variances into a covariance matrix.

```
sigma <- function(theta=0, lambda=c(1,1)) {
  cos.t <- cos(theta); sin.t <- sin(theta)
  a <- matrix(c(cos.t, sin.t, -sin.t, cos.t), ncol=2)
  t(a) %*% diag(lambda) %*% a
}
library(MASS)
n1 <- 50   # First group population
n2 <- 75   # Second group population
x <- rbind(mvrnorm(n1, c(-2,-1), sigma(0, c(1/2,1))),
           mvrnorm(n2, c(0,1), sigma(pi/3, c(1, 1/3))))
```

**Adjoin the orthogonal error and rotate:**

```
eps <- 0.25  # Error SD should be small compared to the SDs for the blobs
x <- cbind(x, matrix(rnorm(dim(x)[1]*(p-2), sd=eps), ncol=p-2))
y <- x %*% rot
```

That's the simulated dataset.  To check it, apply PCA:

```
fit <- prcomp(y)          # PCA
summary(fit)              # Brief summary showing two principal components
par(mfrow=c(2,2))         # Prepare to plot
plot(fit$x[, 1:2], asp=1) # Display the first two components $
plot(x[, 1:2], asp=1);    # Display the original data for comparison
points(x[1:n1,1:2], col="Blue") #...distinguish one of the blobs
screeplot(fit)            # The usual screeplot, supporting the summary
zapsmall(rot %*% fit$rotation, digits=2) # Compare the fitted and simulated rotations.
```

[image: Graphics]

The final check produces a matrix whose block form (an upper 2 by 2 block and lower 3 by 3 block with near-zeros elsewhere) confirms the accuracy of the PCA estimates:

```
       PC1   PC2   PC3   PC4   PC5
[1,]  0.58  0.81  0.05  0.00 -0.01
[2,]  0.81 -0.58  0.00  0.00  0.00
[3,] -0.01 -0.01  0.23 -0.62 -0.75
[4,]  0.03  0.03 -0.96 -0.28 -0.06
[5,]  0.00  0.00  0.18 -0.73  0.66
```

(The upper 2 by 2 block, suitably scaled by the first two eigenvalues, approximately describes the relationship between the point in the "fit" plot and those in the "original components" plot.  This one looks like a rotation and a reflection.)

Comment: thanks a lot for this great post! I haven't yet fully understood your way of doing it but it's now much closer to what I'd like to have. I think I can adjust the values in here: x <- rbind(mvrnorm(n1, c(-2,-1), sigma(0, c(1/2,1))),
           mvrnorm(n2, c(0,1), sigma(pi/3, c(1, 1/3)))) to achieve the data I want! thanks very much again for that great peace of code!