# Implications of doing a confirmatory factor analysis with a correlation matrix as input instead of a variance-covariance matrix?

Tags: factor-analysis, covariance-matrix, confirmatory-factor

Is this possible, and if so what are the implications of doing things one way rather than another.

Is one approach generally preferable? So far I have only been taught to use a variance-covariance matrix.

Comment: Absolutely the same way (corr matrix is cov matrix of standardized variables). Actually, in FA corr is used more often. However, the results, of course, will be different, if the variances of the variables were not all the same.

Comment: There once was a discussion about implications: http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/62677/3277. It is about PCA, but the same is valid about FA.