# Scaling of linear discriminant from lda in MASS

Tags: r, discriminant-analysis

I was attempting to replicate in R an example my instructor used in class from SPSS. However, it looks like the `lda$scaling` value function from `MASS` reports "a matrix which transforms observations to discriminant functions, normalized so that within groups covariance matrix is spherical." Thus, my linear discriminants are different than those from class. While I am aware standardizing the data does not matter [(per this discussion)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/109071/standardizing-features-when-using-lda-as-a-pre-processing-step), I am not sure if this is what is happening in `lda$scaling`.

Do the values reported by `lda$scaling` follow the same process as described in the linked discussion, and thus does not matter in interpretation?

How do I 'un-scale' the linear discriminants so they match output from SPSS?

Here is a reproducible example:

```
require(MASS)

gp.Y1=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4)
cm.x1=c(99,97,94,95,93,94,97,96,99,95,66,67,66,68,62,62,62,63,70,65,67,64,60,66,66,66,69,66,69,70,64,67,61,66,64,62,65,63,60,70)
ap.x2=c(61,61,61,67,65,65,62,62,68,68,85,85,85,80,84,86,87,84,81,89,69,68,64,62,70,65,62,70,63,66,70,61,64,67,69,68,62,61,67,66)
cp.x3=c(88,82,87,75,80,74,89,77,81,74,89,83,81,79,83,72,76,82,87,84,74,74,71,80,89,80,85,88,84,71,73,82,82,80,84,89,72,89,86,72)

df=as.data.frame(cbind(gp.Y1,cm.x1,ap.x2,cp.x3))

mylda=lda(gp.Y1~cm.x1+ap.x2+cp.x3,data=df)
mylda$scaling
```

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/82497/3277 too.