# Standardizing data in Principal Component Analysis?

Tags: pca

Since PCA is sensitive to scaling, I am thinking of standardizing each explanatory variable to have mean 0 and standard deviation 1. What are the drawbacks of such a standardization?
Thank you.

Comment: This is called doing PCA with the correlation matrix.

Comment: May be worth reading http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/62677/3277.