# How to create an arbitrary covariance matrix

Tags: r, random-generation, covariance-matrix

For example, in `R`, the `MASS::mvrnorm()` function is useful for generating data to demonstrate various things in statistics.  It takes a mandatory `Sigma` argument which is a symmetric matrix specifying the covariance matrix of the variables. How would I create a symmetric $n\times n$ matrix with arbitrary entries?

Comment: Related: [How to efficiently generate random positive-semidefinite correlation matrices?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2746)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Create an $n\times n$  matrix $A$ with arbitrary values

and then use $\Sigma = A^T A$ as your covariance matrix.

For example

```
n <- 4  
A <- matrix(runif(n^2)*2-1, ncol=n) 
Sigma <- t(A) %*% A
```

Comment: Likewise, `Sigma <- A + t(A)`.

Comment: @MoazzemHossen: Your suggestion will produce a symmetric matrix, but it may not always be positive semidefinite (e.g. your suggestion could produce a matrix with negative eigenvalues) and so it may not be suitable as a covariance matrix

Comment: Yes, I noticed that R returns error in the event my suggested way produced unsuitable matrix.

Comment: Note that if you prefer a correlation matrix for better interpretability, there is the [?cov2cor](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/cor.html) function, which can be applied subsequently.

Comment: @B11b: You need your covariance matrix to be positive semi-definite.  That would put some limits on the covariance values, not totally obvious ones when $n \gt 2$

Comment: thank you for your reply @Henry. Please can you write what you said as a clear command in R? I will be happy. Thank you so much

Comment: @B11b try the `matrixcalc` or `sfsmisc` or `corpcor` packages or some of the others mentioned in other answers to see if they have what you are looking for

Answer (score 50):

**I like to have control over the objects I create, even when they might be arbitrary.**

Consider, then, that all possible $n\times n$ covariance matrices $\Sigma$ can be expressed in the form

$$\Sigma= P^\prime\ \text{Diagonal}(\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\ldots, \sigma_n)\ P$$

where $P$ is an orthogonal matrix and $\sigma_1 \ge \sigma_2 \ge \cdots \ge \sigma_n \ge 0$.

Geometrically this describes a covariance structure with a range of *principal components* of sizes $\sigma_i$.  These components point in the directions of the rows of $P$.  See the figures at [Making sense of principal component analysis, eigenvectors & eigenvalues](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/2698/919) for examples with $n=3$.  Setting the $\sigma_i$ will set the magnitudes of the covariances and their relative sizes, thereby determining any desired ellipsoidal shape.  The rows of $P$ orient the axes of the shape as you prefer.

One algebraic and computing benefit of this approach is that when $\sigma_n \gt 0$, $\Sigma$ is readily inverted (which is a common operation on covariance matrices):

$$\Sigma^{-1} = P^\prime\ \text{Diagonal}(1/\sigma_1, 1/\sigma_2, \ldots, 1/\sigma_n)\ P.$$

Don't care about the directions, but only about the ranges of sizes of the the $\sigma_i$?  That's fine: you can easily generate a random orthogonal matrix.  Just wrap $n^2$ iid standard Normal values into a square matrix and then orthogonalize it.  It will almost surely work (provided $n$ isn't huge). The QR decomposition will do that, as in [this code](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/35035/919)

```
n <- 5
p <- qr.Q(qr(matrix(rnorm(n^2), n)))
```

This works because the $n$-variate multinormal distribution so generated is "elliptical": it is invariant under all rotations and reflections (through the origin).  Thus, all orthogonal matrices are generated uniformly, as argued at [How to generate uniformly distributed points on the surface of the 3-d unit sphere?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7977/how-to-generate-uniformly-distributed-points-on-the-surface-of-the-3-d-unit-sphe/7984#7984).

A quick way to obtain $\Sigma$ from $P$ and the $\sigma_i$, once you have specified or created them, uses `crossprod` and exploits `R`'s re-use of arrays in arithmetic operations, as in this example with $\sigma=(\sigma_1, \ldots, \sigma_5) = (5,4,3,2,1)$:

```
Sigma <- crossprod(p, p*(5:1))
```

As a check, the Singular Value decomposition should return both $\sigma$ and $P^\prime$.  You may inspect it with the command

```
svd(Sigma)
```

The inverse of `Sigma` of course is obtained merely by changing the multiplication by $\sigma$ into a division:

```
Tau <- crossprod(p, p/(5:1))
```

You may verify this by viewing `zapsmall(Sigma %*% Tau)`, which should be the $n\times n$ identity matrix.  A *generalized inverse* (essential for regression calculations) is obtained by replacing any $\sigma_i \ne 0$ by $1/\sigma_i$, exactly as above, but keeping any zeros among the $\sigma_i$ as they were.

Comment: It might help to demonstrate how to use the rows of $P$ to orient the axes as preferred.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that the singular values in `svd(Sigma)` will be reordered -- that confused me for a minute.

Comment: @whuber could you edit please the line of code to parametrize n: crossprod(p, p*(n:1)). In order to improve reproducibility, good answer!

Comment: @CristóbalAlcázar Thank you for your comment.  Because that's a specific example and is not intended for general purposes, I think it's best to keep the values hard-coded as they are.

Comment: @FrankD Many implementations of SVD do not specify that the singular values they return will be ordered, but in every case I have seen -- including the `svd` function in `R` -- they are ordered by decreasing value.  Since in this post I initially specified an ordered sequence of singular values, the results returned by `svd` ought to be identical to the input, even up to order.

Answer (score 11):

You can simulate random positive definite matrices from the Wishart distribution using the function "rWishart" from stats (included in base)

```
n <- 4
rWishart(1,n,diag(n))
```

From the [documentation](https://rdrr.io/r/stats/rWishart.html) for rWishart:

Usage should be:

```
rWishart(n, df, Sigma)
```

where,

- n: the number of samples.
- df: the degrees of freedom, i.e. the number of dimensions of the matrix.
- Sigma: a positive definite scaling matrix.

Answer (score 4):

There is a package specifically for that, `clusterGeneration` (written among other by Harry Joe, a big name in that field).

There are two main functions:

- `genPositiveDefMat` generate a covariance matrix, 4 different methods
- `rcorrmatrix` : generate a correlation matrix

Quick example:

```r
library(clusterGeneration)
#> Loading required package: MASS
genPositiveDefMat("unifcorrmat",dim=3)
#> $egvalues
#> [1] 15.408962  5.673916  1.228842
#> 
#> $Sigma
#>          [,1]     [,2]     [,3]
#> [1,] 6.714871 1.643449 6.530493
#> [2,] 1.643449 6.568033 2.312455
#> [3,] 6.530493 2.312455 9.028815
genPositiveDefMat("eigen",dim=3)
#> $egvalues
#> [1] 8.409136 4.076442 2.256715
#> 
#> $Sigma
#>            [,1]       [,2]      [,3]
#> [1,]  2.3217300 -0.1467812 0.5220522
#> [2,] -0.1467812  4.1126757 0.5049819
#> [3,]  0.5220522  0.5049819 8.3078880
```

<sup>Created on 2019-10-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Finally, note that an alternative approach is to do a first try from scratch, then use `Matrix::nearPD()` to make your matrix positive-definite.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I still want the eigenvalues to be randomly drawn so, to control the condition number of the covariance matrix does not exceed, say, $\kappa > 1$, one can generate $\sigma_k = 1 + (\kappa - 1) \cdot \mathcal{U}_k$ where $\mathcal{U}_k$ is uniformly sampled in $[0,1]$ for all $k=1,\dots,n$.

Following @whuber (very comprehensive) algorithm, here is a code snippet in Python with all kinds of assertions and data reshaping.

```py
import numpy as np
d = 5
sigmas = np.arange(1, 6).reshape(-1, 1)  # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
# or sigmas = (1 + (kappa - 1) * np.random.uniform(size = d)).reshape(-1, 1)
Q, R = np.linalg.qr(np.random.normal(size = d**2).reshape(d, d))

S = Q.T @ (sigmas * Q)
# Check that S is psd
assert np.all(np.linalg.eigvals(S) > 0)
# Check that S is symmetric
assert np.allclose(S.T, S)
S
_, sigmas_, Q_ = np.linalg.svd(S)
# Check SVD retrieves original parameters
assert np.allclose(np.abs(Q), np.abs(Q_[::-1]))  # up to sign
assert np.allclose(sigmas.reshape(-1), sigmas_[::-1])
```