# Uniformly sampling surface of an ellipsoid using multivariate Gaussian

Tags: uniform-distribution, random-generation, geometry

Sampling uniformly from the surface of an ellipsoid (in the sense of $\mu(dA) = \frac{1}{A}$) seems very nontrivial:

- [How to sample uniformly from the surface of a hyper-ellipsoid (constant Mahalanobis distance)?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/367136/how-to-sample-uniformly-from-the-surface-of-a-hyper-ellipsoid-constant-mahalano)
- [How to generate points uniformly distributed on the surface of an ellipsoid?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/973101/how-to-generate-points-uniformly-distributed-on-the-surface-of-an-ellipsoid)
- [Random uniform points on the surface of (hyper) ellipsoid](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4577181/random-uniform-points-on-the-surface-of-hyper-ellipsoid?noredirect=1&lq=1)

with most suggesting rejection sampling.

On the other hand, a common approach for sampling on the $d$-sphere uses the spherical symmetry of the standard multivariate Gaussian to use $\frac{v}{||v||}$. More generally, for a zero-mean multivariate Gaussian with covariance $\Sigma$, the ellipsoids
$$
v^\intercal \Sigma^{-1}v = c^2
$$
are sets of constant density. Yet, the following naive approach does not work (I assume due to inhomogeneous change in the area element):

$v \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \Sigma)$, construct samples $x = \frac{v}{\sqrt{v^\intercal \Sigma^{-1}v}}$

Yet, can we not use the level sets of a multivariate gaussian somehow to sample an ellipsoid uniformly without rejection?

Comment: One way is to generate points in an equal-area projection of the ellipsoid.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection_of_the_triaxial_ellipsoid.