# Use R to generate random positive definite matrix with zero constraints

Tags: r, matrix

How to use R to generate a random symmetric positive definite matrix with zero constraints?

For example, I would like to generate a 4 by 4 random symmetric positive definite matrix $\Omega\in\mathbb{R}^{4\times4}$, and we know $\Omega_{1,2}=\Omega_{2,1}=\Omega_{1,3}=\Omega_{3,1} = 0$. How can I do that in R?

---

What I had in mind is something like Cholesky decomposition $LL^T=\Omega$, where row $L_i$ and row $L_j$ are orthogonal if $\Omega_{ij}=0$. Possibly solve by the Lagrangian multiplier. But I am not really sure how to implement this. Or if this is possible at all.

Comment: I haven't thought about it deeply, but what I have in my mind is that you cannot randomly generate a PD matrix with an equal probability. Think that any positive constant times the identity matrix is positive definite and we cannot even randomly choose a positive number from positive real numbers unless you employ a proper distribution on the range.

Comment: @Stati Thanks. I am looking for a general way to generate PD with zero constraints. Of course, $cI$ satisfies the zeros, but it is not general. Also, I understand that some zero structures are simply less "likely", or are hard, to generate a PD random matrix.

Comment: Yes, $cI$ is an extreme case. However, if you cannot generate it even in a restrictive situation, it would be much harder to do that in general.

Comment: Generate the non-zero elements in the subdiagonal part of the matrix, eg from an Exponential distribution, complete by symmetry and check for definite positivity. If not, repeat, &tc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every $d\times d$ symmetric positive (semi)definite matrix $\Sigma$ can be factored as

$$\Sigma = \Lambda^\prime\, Q^\prime \,Q\,\Lambda$$

where $Q$ is an orthonormal matrix and $\Lambda$ is a diagonal matrix with non-negative(positive) entries $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_d.$  ($\Sigma$ is always the covariance matrix of *some* $d$-variate distribution and $QQ^\prime$ will be its correlation matrix; the $\lambda_i$ are the standard deviations of the marginal distributions.)

**Let's interpret this formula.**  The $(i,j)$ entry $\Sigma_{i,j}$ is the dot product of columns $i$ and $j$ of $Q$, multiplied by $\lambda_i\lambda_j.$  Thus, *the zero-constraints on $\Sigma$ are orthogonality constraints on the dot products of the columns of $Q.$*

(Notice that all diagonal entries of a positive-definite matrix must be nonzero, so I assume the zero-constraints are all off the diagonal.  I also extend any constraint on the $(i,j)$ entry to a constraint on the $(j,i)$ entry, to assure symmetry of the result.)

**One (completely general) way to impose such constraints is to generate the columns of $Q$ sequentially.**  Use any method you please to create a $d\times d$ matrix of initial values.  At step $i=1,2,\ldots, d,$ alter column $i$ regressing it on all the columns $1, 2, \ldots, i-1$ of $Q$ that need to be orthogonal to it and retaining the residuals.  Normalize those results so their dot product (sum of squares) is unity.  That is column $i$ of $Q.$

Having created an instance of $Q,$ randomly generate the diagonal of $\Lambda$ any way you please (as discussed in the closely related answer at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/215647/919).

The following `R` function `rQ` uses *iid* standard Normal variates for the initial values by default.  I have tested it extensively with dimensions $d=1$ through $200,$ checking systematically that the intended constraints hold.  I also tested it with Poisson$(0.1)$ variates, which--because they are likely to be zero--generate highly problematic initial solutions.

The principal input to `rQ` is a logical matrix indicating where the zero-constraints are to be applied.  Here is an example with the constraints specified in the question.

> ```
> set.seed(17)
> Q <- matrix(c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE,
>               TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE,
>               TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE,
>               FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), 4)
> Lambda <- rexp(4)
> zapsmall(rQ(Q, Lambda))
> ```

```
         [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]
[1,] 2.646156  0.000000  0.000000  2.249189
[2,] 0.000000  0.079933  0.014089 -0.360013
[3,] 0.000000  0.014089  0.006021 -0.055590
[4,] 2.249189 -0.360013 -0.055590  4.167296
```

As a convenience, you may pass the diagonal of $\Lambda$ as the second argument to `rQ`.  Its third argument, `f`, must be a random number generator (or any other function for which `f(n)` returns a numeric vector of length `n`).

```R
rQ <- function(Q, Lambda, f=rnorm) {
  normalize <- function(x) {
    v <- zapsmall(c(1, sqrt(sum(x * x))))[2]
    if (v == 0) v <- 1
    x / v
  }
  Q <- Q | t(Q)                    # Force symmetry by applying all constraints
  d <- nrow(Q) 
  if (missing(Lambda)) Lambda <- rep(1, d)
  R <- matrix(f(d^2), d, d)        # An array of column vectors
  for (i in seq_len(d)) {
    j <- which(Q[seq_len(i-1), i]) # Indices of the preceding orthogonal vectors
    R[, i] <- normalize(residuals(.lm.fit(R[, j, drop=FALSE], R[, i])))
  }
  R <- R %*% diag(Lambda)
  crossprod(R)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but for the *specific example you gave* (this doesn't necessarily generalize easily to *arbitrary* zero constraints, as the algebra can get messy!)

- if $L$ is a lower-triangular matrix with positive values on the diagonal then $\Omega = L L^\top$ is positive definite (requiring the diagonal to be positive is not necessary for positive definiteness, but makes the decomposition unique: see Pinheiro and Bates 1996 "Unconstrained parametrizations for variance-covariance  matrices").
- $\Omega_{12} = L_{11} L_{21}$ and $\Omega_{13} = L_{11} L_{31}$. Thus, I *think* that without any further loss of generality, a lower-triangular matrix with a positive diagonal and $L_{21} = L_{31} = 0$ will give you the constraint pattern you want. (Setting $L_{11}=0$ would give you a singular matrix.)
- "random" is pretty vague. (You didn't say "uniform" ...) We could for example pick $\theta_{ii} \sim U(0,20)$, $\theta_{ij} \sim U(-10,10)$ (for $i \neq j$ and $\{i,j\}$ not equal to $\{2,1\}$ or $\{3,1\}$).

```r
set.seed(101)
m <- matrix(0, 4, 4)
diag(m) <- runif(4, max=20)
m[lower.tri(m)] <- runif(6, min=-10, max=10)
m[2,1] <- m[3,1] <- 0
S <- m %*% t(m)
S
         [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]
[1,] 55.41265  0.0000000   0.000000  12.634888
[2,]  0.00000  0.7682458  -2.919309   2.138861
[3,]  0.00000 -2.9193087 212.553839   4.881917
[4,] 12.63489  2.1388607   4.881917 182.698471

eigen(S)$values

[1] 213.387898 183.174454  54.170033   0.700823
```

Comment: Is positive diagonal in $L$ even required for $\Sigma = LL^T$ to be PD?

Comment: I get 0.02% non-PD matrices when not restricting diagonals vs 0.05% non-PD matrices when restricting the diagonal to be positive (in 10x10 matrices, to exacerbate numerical errors).

Comment: See edits .....

Comment: Great! I always searched for that reference as well, was needing it for a project actually, so thank you!

Answer (score -1):

First, generate the random symmetric matrix.
Second, apply ledoit wolf regularization to make it SPD.

Comment: Does ledoit wolf regularization keeps sparsity?