# On distributions over orthonormal sets: existing families, construction, and simulation

Tags: probability, distributions, references, linear-algebra, random-matrix

1. Have families of distributions over orthonormal sets been defined and studied in the literature? What are a couple examples and/or references?
2. Are there known methods for constructing distributions over orthonormal sets by, for example, parameterizing the distributions of each coordinate of each vector?
3. As a follow-up to question (2) above, how does one simulate orthonormal sets by, for example, parameterizing some distribution over each coordinate and vector?

Consider an orthonormal set of dimension $n$. For question (3), I imagine one could define a procedure that begins by simulating a unit vector from a distribution of dimension $n-1$, and iteratively simulate from the remaining $n-2$ orthonormal basis vectors. However, beyond the first unit vector, how might one impose the mutually orthogonal constraint?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/215647/919 for one way -- one of the most efficient -- to generate uniformly distributed orthonormal matrices.  The issue in most cases isn't imposing orthogonality--that's easy algebra--but rather *computing the conditional distribution* after a preliminary set of orthonormal vectors has been selected.  Doing that depends on what distribution you have in mind.  It's rare to see anything but a uniform (Haar) distribution used on compact Lie groups or their quotient spaces.

Comment: thanks @whuber; your answer there also has some nice references I can follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Will update with details as I learn.)

1. Yes. A [Haar measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_measure) is essentially a uniform distribution over the set of all orthogonal matrices. Orthogonal matrices of dimension $n$ are also known as [orthogonal groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_group#Group_structure), denoted $\mathrm{O}(n)$.
2. and 3. Yes. For example, one could use the [Gram-Schmidt process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) (GSP) which [orthogonalizes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonalization) a set of vectors in an iterative manner. This is a deterministic procedure, but randomness can be injected by initializing a set of random vectors and applying the GSP to these vectors. The resulting matrix will correspond to the Q matrix in [QR decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition). The Wikipedia article on orthogonalization lists [other methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonalization#Orthogonalization_algorithms) that can be leveraged in the same manner as above. For sampling from the Haar distribution, see [How to generate random matrices from the classical compact groups](https://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0609050v2) (used in SciPy's [ortho_group](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ortho_group.html) function).

Relevant references:

1. [Technical report: The Subgroup Algorithm for Generating Uniform Random Variables](https://purl.stanford.edu/jr176nf6321)
2. [MathSE: "Random" generation of rotation matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/442418/random-generation-of-rotation-matrices)
3. [MathSE: What does "Random Rotation Matrix" really mean? How to generate it?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3382804/what-does-random-rotation-matrix-really-mean-how-to-generate-it)